# Check multiple chunks of string against a range in excel in one go

Tags: excel

I have a range of "Good" values like this:

```
Apple
Banana
Pear
Grape
Melon
```

And a range of input data like this ( I could probably hardcode a max of 10 `;` separated elements if I had to):

```
Apple; Grape  //Good
Watermellon   //bad
Pear; Peach   //bad, ideally return "Peach"
```

I'm trying to come up with a function to check each cell of the input data against the acceptable values. So it should take "Watermelon" or "Pear;Peach" and return FALSE  (ideally it would give me the strings that caused FALSE), and TRUE for "Apple"

VBA is not acceptable.

I know how to check an individual string like "Apple", but not how to check multiple substrings at once. I tried a mess of `FIND` + `MID` lookups, but felt like there must be a better way. Is there?

Comment: If you don't want VBA, consider asking this on serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm programmatically generating a .xlsx file that other people are filling in, so I really want to avoid distributing an add-in or something, unless there's an easy way?

Comment: @Inafziger I only see ~500 threads about excel on all of serverfault.com, and they're mostly related to administration

Comment: Well, this is their **programming** site (for questions about things like vba) and usually questions such as these get referred over there.  No worries, just thought you might get more help there.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, though I think it fits better here. If this question has a clean answer it's going to involve a bit of fancy function manipulation of which I'm more hopeful here.

Comment: If VBA is unacceptable then this question belongs on Super User

Comment: @Inafziger it belongs to super user, not server fault.

Answer (score 1):

Without vba, it will be messy. One way if you can accept manual steps is to use the text to columns feature in excel, using ; as a delimiter.

If you know that you can't have more than 10 items, you could have 10 columns with one item or blank in each using text o columns or a combination of find, mid. It would be a little less messy and would allow you to spot which colum contains an invalid value with vlookups or conditional formatting for example.